# AKS - the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to create a SQL server instance in AKS. My PV and PVC looks like this,

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mssql-data-pv-02
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 350Gi
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  azureDisk:
    kind: Managed
    diskName: XXXXX
    diskURI: /subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/XXXXX
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-data-pvc-02
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 256Gi
```

And Deployment and Service looks like this

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-02
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql-02
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql-02
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mssql-02
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "0.25"
          limits:
            memory: "3Gi"
            cpu: "1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PID
          value: "Developer"
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mssql
              key: SA_PASSWORD
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mssqldb
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-data-pvc-02
          
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-02
spec:
  selector:
    app: mssql-02
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
  type: LoadBalancer
```

My AKS is using Managed Identity. The disk I'm using resides in a different resource group. But I have given Contributor access to the managed identity.

> AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "mssql-data-pv-02" : Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 403, RawError: Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 403, RawError: {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client '9a2f4007-5a2b-4069-9eac-a0c9aeff67f9' with object id '9a2f4007-5a2b-4069-9eac-a0c9aeff67f9' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/itm-disk-01' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

I have tried finding the client with that Guid, but can't seem to find.Help will be much appreciated, this became a critical issue.

Comment: Aside... the [memory resources and limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/developer-best-practices-resource-management#pod-cpumemory-limits) are set very low. [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) requires **at least** 2GiB RAM and, unless you use [mssql-conf to set memory limits otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#memorylimit), it will easily blow past your 3GiB limit and so get killed by AKS.

Comment: Hey, there. I have increased it. But the issue I'm getting is due to Volume Attachment.

Comment: Hello @TahmidEshayat, was the issue resolved?

Comment: if not can you try searching the client id by going to your Azure Active Directory Page and providing the same client id you get in error in the search box like [Image](https://i.imgur.com/ADssk03.png). the strange thing I notice is that the object Id and the Client ID are the same , which should not be possible ..

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, Unfortunately, It wasn't solved. There seem to be an issue with managed identity when using existing disk. So We rebuild the whole VM. Fortunately it was a DEV/TEST sql server instance so the impact was low. 

But thanks for your suggestion, But I believe there is still some issues with using Managed Identity with AKS, so for the new cluster i used service credentials, and so far working fine

Comment: can you please post the same workaround that you have tried as an answer so that its helpful for the community